# C program that reverses a string

Tags: c, strings

As practice with the (ever so painful) C Strings I wrote a string reversal program. I am new to C, so I wanted to make sure that I am not using bad coding practices. It runs just fine (at least with expected input), but I am not sure if the logic is as good as it could be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* strreverse(char* c) 
{
    char input[500], output[500] = {}, buffer[2] = {' ', '\0'};
    strcpy(input, c);
    int i;
    for(i = strlen(input); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        buffer[0] = input[i];
        strcat(output, buffer);
    }
    return (char*) output;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* in = malloc(256);
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", in);
    char* out = strreverse(in);
    printf("%s", out);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could actually do the reversing in-place? You'd get some pretty good performance this way (swapping some characters around)

Comment: Your specification -- reverse a string -- is a good start, but at three words, is too short. Say whether your function reverses in-place or allocates a new string, whether there are restrictions on the string, what to do if the string is null, and so on.  Then show us your specification *and the test cases which verify it*.

Comment: This code returns the address of a temporary `output[]`.  This is undefined behavior and a major code flaw.  Goods answer should mention that.

Comment: "ever so painful C Strings". I hear that!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Implementation:

As of now, the code is not practical, because the limit is 500 chars including zero termination. It does unnecessary copying. You need to determine the actual length of the string by relying on the fact that C strings are null terminated.

```
size_t length = 0;
while (*(str + length) != 0)
{
    ++length;
}
```

Notice that I'm using size_t, because it is meant to be used to describe **size of the objects in memory**. Despite it is easy to do it manually, you should always use `strlen` when possible:

```
size_t length = strlen(str);
```

It should be noted that the function returns the length **without** null terminator. Then we allocate memory for result, since we are creating new string, rather than making changes in place:

```
char* result = malloc(length + 1);
if (result == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

We check for succession of allocation, as was suggested in the comments. If allocation failed, further operations will definitely invoke undefined behavior, so we return NULL. `length + 1` is for null terminator. Then, we immediately null terminate it:

```
result[length] = 0;
```

Now we need to capture the position of the last character in the original string, to start copying from there. It is right before null terminator, which is on index `length`, so needed position is `length - 1`. There is an edge case of length 0, so we should check for that first

```
if (length == 0)
{
    return result;
}
size_t last = length - 1;
```

Then we write algorithm that writes contents of the first string into the second in reverse order:

```
size_t it = 0;
while (it <= last)
{
    result[it] = str[last - it];
    ++it;
}
```

then simply return the result:

```
return result;
```

Although the implementation has good performance, there are some opportunities to make micro optimizations. The function input type should be `const char*`, since we don't modify original string. Additionally, it should be noted that the caller is responsible for freeing up `malloc`'d memory.

## Cosmetics:

Name of the function is a little hard to read, so I'd suggest `str_reverse`. Also, `c` is not good name at all, so it would be better if it's name `str`

## Put together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* str_reverse(const char* str)
{
    size_t length = strlen(str);

    char* result = malloc(length + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    result[length] = 0;

    if (length == 0)
    {
        return result;
    }

    size_t last = length - 1;
    size_t it = 0;
    while (it <= last)
    {
        result[it] = str[last - it];
        ++it;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    const char* str = "ABCD";
    char* reversed = str_reverse(str);

    printf("%s\n", reversed);
    if (str[4] != 0)
    {
        printf("problems\n");
    }

    free(reversed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42337/discussion-on-answer-by-olzhas-zhumabek-c-program-that-reverses-a-string).

Answer (score 26):

#### Returning a pointer to a local variable

Returning a pointer to the local variable `output` is incorrect.  It may happen to work but it is wrong to do so, because the storage for that local variable goes out of scope the moment you return from the function.  To be correct, you should either malloc a buffer and return it (preferred) or make `output` be `static`.

#### Empty initializer list

Initializing `output` to `{}` is nonstandard C and should be avoided.  The standard way to initialize an array to zeroes is `{0}`.

#### Unnecessary variable

Your `input` variable is unnecessary because you can just use `c` wherever you used `input`.

#### Bad algorithm

Your string reversal function takes \$O(n^2)\$ time when it should only take \$O(n)\$ time.  The problem is that you use `strcat` to append one character at a time, and `strcat` needs to find the end of the string each time.  If you ever find yourself using `strcat` in a loop, it's probably not the best way.

#### Other things

- Using `scanf("%s",in);` to read into a fixed size string is unsafe and could result in a buffer overflow.
- You should also print a newline when you print the result otherwise your shell prompt will be on the same line as your output.
- Your function argument `c` could be marked `const` since you do not modify it.  Also, `c` sounds like a character not a string.
- Since you are already using C99 style variable declarations, you can put the `int i` declaration inside the `for` loop.

#### Suggested rewrite

```
char *reverseString(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char  *ret = calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));

    if (ret == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0, j = len-1; i < len; i++, j--)
        ret[i] = str[j];
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: While `sizeof(char)` may be nice if you want to change the type, `sizeof(char)` is defined to always return `1`.

Comment: @pipe I know but I like to have sizeof something there otherwise it "looks wrong" to me.

Comment: Fine, I won't argue with that. Just thought it's worth commenting on, maybe it helps someone understand why you put it there. :)

Comment: @JS1 At the time i was unaware u could loop through a char*. Can you edit individual chars in a char?

Comment: @NullSpark, actually you can loop through the memory to which char* or const char* is pointing to and use operator [] (subscript operator) to get access to the individual element. The difference is that the former provides read-write access, whereas the latter only read. Be aware that you can get out of range, which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Recommend `some_type *ret = calloc(len+1, sizeof *ret);` to avoid insure code uses the right`sizeof(char)`.  `sizeof *ret` will always be right. (Best review so far).

Answer (score 18):

> ```
>     char input[500], output[500] = {}, buffer[2] = {' ', '\0'};
> ```

This is not a good way to allocate memory in C.  What this means in C is that the memory is only guaranteed unique during the scope of the function.  So if you have

```
str1 = strreverse(input1);
str2 = strreverse(input2);
```

Then `str1` and `str2` will often both point to the reverse of `input2`, as you wrote over the first call on `input1`.

This can happen in two different ways.  Sometimes the compiler will allocate a small amount of memory to the function and leave it allocated for the entire program.  You can force it to happen that way by declaring the variables as `static` which says that the same variable will be used throughout the program's duration.

The second way that this can happen is that the memory can be implicitly allocated and deallocated during the scope of the function call.  Then the memory is available to be allocated to someone else.  If you call the same function twice in a row, it is possible if not likely to allocate the same memory both times.  But in some ways it is worse if you do other things in between.  Then the memory that pointed to `output` the first time may be used for other variables and get overwritten wholly or partially by other operations.

Which method it uses is up to the compiler (unless you make the variable `static` in which case it will always do it the first way; or make the function recursive in which case it can't do it the first way).  The key point is that you should not rely on this pattern producing correct or even predictable results.  Unlike a garbage collected language, C does not track memory usage until it has no pointers to it.  It deallocates static allocations based on scope.

The first method is static allocation on the [.bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss#BSS_in_C) or [data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data) segments.  The second method is automatic allocation (which is still static) using the stack.  If you use `malloc` or another dynamic allocation method, you are using heap allocation.  If you want to read more about how this works, you might start with [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923)  You can follow up with the [Difference between static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15793111).

The more normal way to handle this is to pass the output string into the function

```
strreverse(in, reversed, maximum_length);
```

Then the function doesn't have to worry about allocating memory.  Another possibility would be to have the function allocate memory with `malloc` or similar, but then you have to explicitly `free` memory allocated implicitly by the function.  By forcing the caller to do that, the caller can figure out how to get the memory allocated and deallocated.

> ```
>     char* in = malloc(256);
> ```

Any time you explicitly allocate memory like this, you should also explicitly `free` the memory.

It won't matter in this program as the program will end and deallocate all the memory right after you would `free` it (and some would leave it out for that reason).  But in a real program this could cause a memory leak.

> ```
>     strcpy(input, c);
> ```

You should use `strncpy` instead.

```
    strncpy(input, c, 500);
    input[499] = '\0';
```

This will guarantee that `c` is never longer than `input` can hold and that `input` is always null terminated.

Alternately, you could check that `c` is no longer than will fit in `input` and do something if it is.

> ```
>     for(i = strlen(input); i >= 0; i--)
>     {
>         buffer[0] = input[i];
> ```

Note that on the first iteration, you will copy the null byte at the end of the string.  The `strcat` function handles this (by copying a zero length string into `output`), but this is pure waste.  This should be

```
    for (i = strlen(input) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        buffer[0] = input[i];
```

Comment: oh... i was unaware that c would allocate the same memory everytime. may i ask how c decides where to store the array?

Comment: Actually `str1 = strreverse(input1);
str2 = strreverse(input2);` will not necessarily both point to the reverse of `input2`. Both will point to the stack address that `output` had at the time of the call to `strreverse` as the calls are at the same call-stack depth they will get the same pointer. Had the calls been at different depth, different pointers should have been returned. The contents of the pointer are likely to be overwritten with garbage the next time you call a function though. Had `output` been `static` then it would have happened as you described.

Answer (score 11):

From your main(), it's obvious that you do not need to store the reversed string separately. Hence, you could reverse the string in place, swapping characters starting at the extremities until you reach the middle. This also has the benefit of using up only half the iterations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void strreverse(char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    int lastCharPos = len - 1;
    int nrOfSwaps = len / 2;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nrOfSwaps; ++i)
    {
        char temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[lastCharPos - i];
        str[lastCharPos - i] = temp;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char* in = malloc(256);
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", in);
    strreverse(in);
    printf("%s\n", in);
    return 0;
}
```

Your input is limited to a max of 255 chars; anything more and there is out-of-bounds memory access. You may want to look at the solutions proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870485/how-can-i-read-an-input-string-of-unknown-length

Comment: You divide by 2 for every loop iteration.  It may be worthwhile to: A) use memory to store len/2, or B) replace "i < len/2" with " ( i << 1) < len" or "i+i < len" or "i*2 < len", as bitshift is faster than add which is faster than non-bit-shifting MUL which is notably faster than DIV, if I remember my x86 op code speeds right ([GameDev question on opcode speed](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27196/which-opcodes-are-faster-at-the-cpu-level)).  Sure, the effect is CPU-dependent, but I'd guess DIV is usually slower.  Subtracting 1 from len, twice in each loop, also looks slower

Comment: @TOOGAM "bitshift is faster than add" may be true with assembly but with C, a good compiler will use the optimal code should code be `i*2` or `i<<1` or in the other case `i/2` or `i>>1` - it will make no executable code difference.  The preferred coding is then what makes most sense to humans or `i*2` in this case.  If a compiler makes sub-optimal code, then the issue is with the compiler and not a good reason for less than clear coding.

Comment: @chux : Correct.  Compilers may re-arrange our code.  Still, why not make the C code actually reflect what the compiler is more likely to do?  I'm just feeling a bit more comfortable with the idea of the code I read (the C code) being more similar to what the computer actually ends up doing, not less similar.  Well, bit shifting may be more unfamiliar for many people, but `(i+i)` or `(2*i)` instead of `(len/2)` may be just as readable, and likely to be closer to compiler's output, and easily readable.  Plus, if code is ported to a compiler that doesn't optimize, using DIV may be expensive.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of building the reversed string in a separate buffer, I would recommend reversing the input string in place:

```
char* strreverse(char* c)
{
    /* construct pointers to beginning and end of string */
    char* cur = c;
    char* end = c + (strlen(c) - 1);

    /* loop until pointers cross each other (midpoint of string) */
    while (cur < end)
    {
        /* swap characters at current and end locations */
        const char tmp = *cur;
        *cur = *end;
        *end = tmp;

        /* move pointers inward */
        cur++;
        end--;
    }

    return c;
}
```

### (Edit) Explanation of how this method works:

For simplicity, let's assume the input string to this function is `"Hello"`.

The function begins by constructing two pointers `cur` and `end` directly into the string.  `cur` is initialized to point the same memory location as the beginning of the string, and `end` is advanced to the length of the string minus 1 (effectively pointing to the last character in the string).  Visually, this looks like the following in memory:

```
cur
v
Hello
    ^
    end
```

As the `end` pointer is located after the `cur` pointer in memory, the characters stored at the current and end memory locations are then swapped:

```
cur
v
oellH
    ^
    end
```

Then both pointers are moved inward; `cur` moves forward and `end` moves backward:

```
 cur
 v
oellH
   ^
   end
```

As `end` is still higher in memory than `cur`, the characters at those locations are then again swapped:

```
 cur
 v
olleH
   ^
   end
```

And then the pointers are again moved inward:

```
  cur
  v
olleH
  ^
  end
```

At this point, the `end` pointer is no longer higher in memory than the `cur` pointer, so the loop ends, and the string is reversed.

Comment: It might be useful to note the return value is always the same as the argument and that you must `strcpy` before calling if you wish to preserve the non-reversed string.

Comment: @richremer : Actually, that means the calling function already has the address, so there's no need to return it (e.g., [Jeryl Vaz's answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/134511/111148).  And, if this turned into a void, we really need both "cur" and "c".  (Just rename "c" to "cur" in the top line, and remove the first variable declaration.)  I'm still up-voting the current version of this answer because I do mostly like it.  (However, sizeof('\0') may be better than the number 1, so that 1 isn't an undocumented magic number.)

Comment: `char* end = c + (strlen(c) - 1);` is undefined behavior should `c == ""`.  Use `char* end = c + strlen(c);` and move `end--;` to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @Falken could u explain why this works? i am very new to c so i find pointer logic to be incredibly confusing.

Comment: @chux Creating a pointer to an invalid memory location is not undefined behavior.  Dereferencing it is, but this code never does that.

Comment: @NullSpark I've added a visual explanation to the post that shows how the code works step-by-step.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @Falken Thank you very much for the diagram. So pointers are kind of like arrows that "point" to a position in memory... things make a lot more sense now. and when u create a string, the pointer points to the first char in tge string.

Comment: @Falken  Disagree, 1) creating an invalid pointer is UB.  2) Code does attempt to reference with `*end`  Detail: `c + (strlen("") - 1)` is the same as `c + SIZE_MAX`, not `c - 1`.

Comment: @chux I think you might want to read up on what undefined behavior actually means.  Declaring a pointer and setting it to any value -- regardless of the memory location it points to -- is well-defined.  Example: `char *a = (char *)0x1000, *b = (char *)0x2000; assert(a < b);` will always be valid, regardless of the platform it executes on.  Remember that a pointer is effectively just an integer value, and the compiler treats it as such for both comparisons and arithmetic.  If you still disagree with me, I'll be happy to take this up with you further in chat.

Comment: @Falken.  "a pointer is effectively just an integer value" --> That may be so in a linear architecture, but C allows for others: 2 example: venerable DOS segment:offset  and Harvard architectures.  Perhaps with `a < b` and "C11 §6.5.8 5" or maybe [Pointer arithmetic on a pointer not pointing to an array is Undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15608422/2410359) may convince you.  If not, suggest posting an SO question.

Comment: @chux After researching this a bit more, you're right: the code does invoke UB according to the standard, as range comparison operators between pointers (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) are not defined for arbitrary memory locations.  My suggestion would indeed fail if a zero-length string (a single byte of `\0`) was unfortunately placed at an offset of 0000h within a given segment.  Thanks for reminding me of how I wrote code 25 years ago.  ;)

Answer (score 10):

There are good points in other answers, just a couple more I didn't see mentioned:

```
char* strreverse(char* c)
```

`c` is a perfectly fine name for a parameter that is a character, less so
for a string. `s` (or `str`) would be more common. Of course both are rather brief, but still used when the context is obvious. (Even some standard functions like [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)).

```
    char output[500] = {};
    return (char*) output;
```

This doesn't just point to the same array each time, but it's actually invalid. `output` falls out of scope when the function returns and the pointer is not valid after that. Declaring it `static` would make it valid but with the problems others have mentioned.

I agree with Jeryl in that a function like this could just reverse the string in-place, and let the caller worry about making a copy if they need it. If they don't, there's no need for another buffer, and if they do, they can do an `strdup`.

```
    buffer[0] = input[i];
    strcat(output, buffer);
```

I would suggest just copying the character to the end of `output` manually, just run another index variable from zero up. Here `strcat` has to find the end of the `output` string every single time, even though you know exactly where it will be on every iteration.

```
int main(void)
    char* in = malloc(256);
    scanf("%s", in);
```

Consider what happens if someone inputs a word longer than 256 characters.
Also, `scanf` interacts badly with line buffering when reading from a terminal. I'd suggest `fgets`.

Answer (score 4):

Critiques of some of the above solutions

Olzhas solution seems bloated. It's doing superfluous checks that a different structure would make shorter. Compare to falken's solution

Falken's solution is not a bad answer per-se but it seems likely to lead to confusion as is. I'd suggest either making it return void which would make it clear nothing new is being allocated. That would also still make it subtle so I'd suggest naming in something clearer like `strreverseInPlace`.

Whether reversing in place is better than making a new string is probably a matter of opinion. For example `strcpy` does not allocate a string. Maybe naming the function `strcpyreverse` would make it clearer it's the same as a `strcpy`

Jeryl's solution is similar to Falken's but it's doing un-needed math in 3 places in the inner loop; The 2 places it computes the index of the characters and the place it checks the length. A good compiler might optimize those out but why ask it to (see Falken's). If the compiler can't optimize it it will be slower.

JS1's solution uses `calloc` which means it's going to visit every byte in the destination twice. Once to clear it then again when copying from the src so it's going to be up to twice as slow

Here's another solution

```
/* like strcpy but in reverse. 
   Assumes dst is big enough to hold result. */
char* strcpyreverse(const char* src, char* dst) {
    // copy from end
    const char* s = src + strlen(src);
    char* d = dst;

    while (s > src) {
      *d++ = *--s;
    }
    *d = '\0';

    return dst;
}
```

Some processors have specific instructions for handling post increment and pre decrement. Of course even if the code isn't written this way an optimizing compiler might figure out a way to use those instructions anyway.

Note this may or may not be faster than using indices, again depending on the processor (and the compiler optimizations) although using direct pointers are arguably more C like. If you wanted to use indices it would be

```
/* like strcpy but in reverse. 
   Assumes dst is big enough to hold result. */
char* strcpyreverse(const char* src, char* dst) {
    // copy from end
    size_t s = strlen(src);
    size_t d = 0;

    while (s > 0) {
      dst[d++] = src[--s];
    }
    dst[d] = '\0';

    return dst;
}
```

In any case code that uses `*somepointer++` is an extremely common pattern in C. If you're new to C it effectively means

```
value = *somepointer;
somepointer += 1;
return value
```

and I have a feeling it specifically exists because the processors that C was first written on had instructions that did exactly that.

If you really want to it to allocate the string there's a common function `strdup` which allocates and copies a string so maybe naming it `strdupreverse` or `strreversedup`

```
/* like strdup but in reverse. */
char* strdupreverse(const char* src) {
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    char* dst = malloc(len + 1);
    if (dst != NULL) { 
        // copy from end
        const char* s = src + len;
        char* d = dst;

        while (s > src) {
          *d++ = *--s;
        }
        *d = '\0';
    }

    return dst;
}
```

Note I'm not checking for `src` being null because neither do any of the standard C string functions IIRC.

Comment: This is the correct approach.  If your goal is to learn C, you'll want to learn how to write idiomatic C.  You find C-strings painful because you're trying to use them as though they were string objects, rather than pointers.  C's low-level approach offers both advantages and disadvantages.  If you don't take advantage of things like pointers, there's really no point in using the language.  (One minor critique: `src` and `s` should be `const char*`, not `char*`.)

Comment: @Ray What is the difference between referring to *char_pointer and char_pointer?

Comment: Thanks for the const comment. It's been so long since I'd written straight C I forgot if it was in C or just C++

Comment: @NullSpark My comment was about `const char*` vs `char*`, not `s` vs. `*s`.  Is that what you were referring to? Regardless, here are the differences between both: Suppose you have `char buf[] = "foo"; char *s = buf; const char *t = buf;`. Then `s` and `t` refer to the address of the first character of the string (and are equal, since they're both pointing to the same physical memory in this case, `buf`).  `*s` and `*t` refer to the character (`'F'`) itself, however you can't modify the string through `*t`, since it points to `const char`: `*s = 'F';` is legal, but `*t = 'F'` is not.

Comment: @NullSpark If that doesn't answer your question, you might consider creating a question on StackOverflow; between the length limit and the inability to format the text, comments aren't really great for explaining the various intricacies of pointer type qualifiers.

Comment: @Ray your comment was very useful, but what my question was trying to say was that after you declared your pointers you referef to the with an '*'. i did not in my program. does this change anything?

Comment: @Ray sorry. your second comment didnt come through until i had already typed mine.

Comment: @NullSpark No problem.  I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking, through.  Were you asking about the code in the answer?  That was gman's, not mine.  But if *that's* the question, then `*s` is equivalent to `s[0]`, and more generally, `*(s + i)` is equivalent to `s[i]`.

Comment: If `s` is a pointer then `*s` is what `s` points to. `char* s = "ab"; printf("%p\n", s); // prints '0x????????'; printf("%c\n", *s); / prints 'a'`

Comment: Nice `strcpyreverse(const char* src, char* dst)`.  (Could use `(const char* restrict src, char* restrict dst)`)

Comment: wow! I can't believe I didn't know about the `restrict` keyword. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just a few points to add to the answers you've already received.

#### Names

The C standard reserves all names at global scope starting with `str` and a lower case letter, so your `strreverse` gives undefined behavior. Renaming it to something like `reverse_string` will fix this (i.e., it's purely the name that matters here).

#### Use of malloc

At least in my opinion, `malloc` should typically be reserved for situations where either you don't know the amount of space you're going to allocate until run-time, or situations where you're allocating so much that it's likely to overflow the stack if you allocate the space on the stack instead of the heap. Your `char* in = malloc(256);` in `main` doesn't qualify on either count. You might as well just define `in` as an array of char and be done with it.

If you were going to put this to real use, it could very well make sense to use `malloc` inside of `strreverse` itself though. In particular, if you couldn't modify the input string, you'd want to allocate a buffer you could return, and in this case `malloc` makes perfect sense:

```
char *reverse_string(char const *input) { 
    size_t size = strlen(input) + 1;

    char *temp = malloc(size);

    /* ... */
```

#### use of `scanf`

When you use `scanf` with the `%s` conversion, it's *crucial* to specify the size of the buffer you're reading into, like:

```
char in[256];
scanf("%255s", in);
```

Note that in this case, what you specify to `scanf` is the maximum number of input characters to accept. It always appends a NUL character after this, so you need to specify one fewer than the size of the buffer you pass (or smaller than that if you don't want to use the whole buffer, but that's rare).

As it is right now, with no length specified, your use of `scanf` is essentially identical to the widely-reviled `gets`.

#### unnecessary casts

I prefer cast-free code whenever possible, so adding casts that aren't necessary at all just grates on my nerves. In your case, you've hit this pet peeve with the return from your `strreverse`:

```
return (char*) output;
```

This is pointless--the name of an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array in most cases (including this one) without any casting. You can just `return output;` and it's fine (other than the fact that you're returning the address of a local, but others have already pointed out the problem with that, and section on using `malloc` above shows how to correct it as well).